# Using dplyr within a function, Grouping Error with function arguments

Tags: r, function, group-by, dplyr

Below I have a working example of what I would like the function to do, and then script for the function, noting where the Error occurs.

The error message is:

```
Error: index out of bounds
```

Which I know usually means R can’t find the variable that’s being called.

Interestingly, in my function example below, if I only group by my  `subgroup_name` (which is passed to the function and  becomes a column in the newly created dataframe) the function will successfully regroup that variable, but I also want to group by a newly created column (from the melt) called variable.

Similar code used to work for me using `regroup()`, but that has been deprecated. I am trying to use `group_by_()` but to no avail.

I have read many other posts and answers and experimented several hours today but still not successful.

```
# Initialize example dataset
database <- ggplot2::diamonds
database$diamond <- row.names(diamonds) # needed for melting 

subgroup_name <- "cut" # can replace with  "color" or "clarity"
subgroup_column <- 2 # can replace with 3 for color, 4 for clarity

# This works, although it would be preferable not to need separate variables for subgroup_name and subgroup_column number

df <- database %>% 
  select(diamond, subgroup_column, x,y,z) %>% 
  melt(id.vars=c("diamond", subgroup_name)) %>% 
  group_by(cut, variable) %>% 
  summarise(value = round(mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),2))

# This does not work, I am expecting the same output as above

subgroup_analysis <- function(database,...){

  df <- database %>% 
    select(diamond, subgroup_column, x,y,z) %>% 
    melt(id.vars=c("diamond", subgroup_name)) %>% 
    group_by_(subgroup_name, variable) %>% # problem appears to be with finding "variable"
    summarise(value = round(mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),2))
    print(df)
}

subgroup_analysis(database, subgroup_column, subgroup_name)
```

Comment: @Richard Scriven - I think I am, with the function call in the last line of the code:  subgroup_analysis(database, subgroup_column, subgroup_name). However, should/could probably pass "cut" and 2 directly instead of the proxy variables. Let me know if I am missing something, and thanks for looking

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't see the final call.  Are you sure you want to do this with dots `...` instead of named arguments?

Comment: I would be happy to use named arguments, and I did experiment that way too. reading about group_by_ lead to tinkering with ... but I am not that experienced with them.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `group_by_(subgroup_name, quote(variable))`

Comment: As a side note, if you plan to assign the result to a new variable, then you may want to remove the `print` call at the end and just write `df`, or not even assign `df` at all in the function.  Otherwise the result prints even when you do `x <- subgroup_analysis(...)`

Comment: Thanks Richard Scriven. Next stop for this baby is actually to go into a ggplot, where I may have more questions :-) Thanks all you guys are great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the NSE [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html):

> If you also want to output variables to vary, you need to pass a list
>   of quoted objects to the .dots argument:

Here, `variable` should be quoted:

```
subgroup_analysis <- function(database,...){

  df <- database %>% 
    select(diamond, subgroup_column, x,y,z) %>% 
    melt(id.vars=c("diamond", subgroup_name)) %>% 
    group_by_(subgroup_name, quote(variable)) %>% 
    summarise(value = round(mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),2))
  print(df)
}

subgroup_analysis(database, subgroup_column, subgroup_name)
```

As mentionned by @RichardScriven, if you plan to assign the result to a new variable, then you may want to remove the `print` call at the end and just write `df`, or not even assign `df` at all in the function

Otherwise the result prints even when you do `x <- subgroup_analysis(...)`